# Gmail like contact selector / tag cloud / chip cloud with profile image android

Tags: android, android-layout, contact-form, tag-cloud, word-cloud

**My goal**

[image]

To create a contact picker (with round image on the left) like gmail does when sending an email. I've done some research finding an EditText cloud and a Chip Cloud, but they do not support images in custom layouts and the adapter only accepts `List<String>`. Does someone have a proper idea of how to implement this or use a library to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView<Person> {
    public ContactsCompletionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Person person) {

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TextView view = (TextView) l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup) getParent(), false);
        view.setText(person.getEmail());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Person defaultObject(String completionText) {
        //Stupid simple example of guessing if we have an email or not
        int index = completionText.indexOf('@');
        if (index == -1) {
            return new Person(completionText, completionText.replace(" ", "") + "@example.com");
        } else {
            return new Person(completionText.substring(0, index), completionText);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Close, but I really want it with an Image view on the left side of the name.

Comment: Ah, I get it in the layoutinflater.

Comment: I am checking if it fixes, coming back to you asap ;)

Comment: It sort of works now, still needs a lot of manual formatting but the base is there. Thanks for support !

Comment: glad to help you happy coding :)